# Testing current user in helper spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, helper

I have this pretty basic helper which relies on `current_user` variable provided by Sorcery in controllers and helpers

```
def current_user_link
    user_link current_user
end

 def user_link(user, html_options = {}, &block)
   link_to user.to_s, user, html_options, &block
 end
```

How can I test this helper?

```
describe UsersHelper do
  describe '#current_user_link' do
    it 'should return a link to the current user' do
      expected_link = link_to current_user.name, current_user
      ???

      expect(current_user_link).to eq expected_link
    end
  end
```

Do I need to stub `current_user` somehow?
   Is it even worth testing?

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solved it.

```
describe '#current_user_link' do
  it 'returns a link to the current user ' do
    user = build(:user)
    expected_link = link_to user.name, user
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)

    expect(helper.current_user_link).to eq(expected_link)
  end
end
```

PSA: dont forget to call your method on `helper`.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to use `current_user` with Sorcery in an Rspec `ApplicationHelper` spec and none of the above answers worked for me.

What worked for me was first defining a `user` with FactoryGirl:

`let(:user) { create(:user) }`

Then, write an example like this:

```
it "does stuff" do
  allow(helper).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  expect(helper.some_method_using_current_user).to do_something
end
```

Key difference is using the `helper` object in the example.

Comment: Thank you! Using `allow(helper)` is what did it for me. I tried using `allow(controller)` and it wasn't doing the trick. I'm in a Helper spec, so it makes sense, but most of the other answers were saying to use `controller`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

simpliest work around is to declare in spec:

`let(:current_user) { create(:user) }`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can `stub` your `current_user`

```
describe UsersHelper do
  describe '#current_user_link' do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
    let(:expected_link) { link_to user.name, user }

    before { allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user) }

    it { expect(current_user_link).to eq(expected_link) }
  end
end
```

or set your user to session
than you should

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

and

```
before { allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:session).and_return(user_id: user.id) }
```

Comment: Hi.
 I still receive `NameError:
       undefined local variable or method \`current_user' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersHelper::CurrentUserLink ...`

Comment: and for `session` too?

Comment: Yes, the same error. I restarted the server, if that matters. It didn't help

Comment: Could you provide RSpec version?

Comment: I did a copy-paste of your code... If you mean an error, [here it is](http://screenshot.su/img/ef/ba/39/efba397ca534d5ee86e3deb32791aa86.jpg)

Comment: what version RSpec do you use 3 or 2?

Comment: 3.     rspec (3.3.0),
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0),
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0),
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101206/discussion-between-just-so-and-oleg-sobchuk).

Comment: add please to your question user_link method

Comment: OK. It's completely irrelevant though:)

Comment: sorry for downvote, it was a mistake, but now it's saying it is locked, I'll try again later.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
describe UsersHelper do
  describe '#current_user_link' do
    it 'should return a link to the current user' do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      allow_any_instance_of(UsersHelper).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)

      expected_link = link_to user.name, user
      expect(current_user_link).to eq(expected_link)
    end
  end
end
```

In the `rails_helper.rb` you need to have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :helper
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing helper modules with RSpec, you need to stub the method in your Rspec::ExampleGroups target...

```rb
    allow_any_instance_of(RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersHelper).to receive(:current_user).and_return user
```

Answer (score 0):

**For those who came from Devise:**

You can simply define the method inside the spec.

```rb
  describe 'option_for_product_weight' do
    before {
      def helper.current_user
        User.first
      end
    }

    subject { helper.option_for_product_weight }

    it 'returns the list' do
      expect(subject).not_to be_empty
    end
  end
```